# error CS0119: Expression denotes a `value', where a `method group' was expected

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, multidimensional-array, unity-game-engine

So, I've been googling a bit now, and I can't seem to locate my error...
I'm simply getting an error 
"error CS0119: Expression denotes a `value`, where a `method group` was expected"
Can someone help me locate the error? I'd usually think I missed a "new", but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
[Serializable]
public class Map {
    public Cell[,] cells;

    public ushort width, height;

    private Map() {
    }

    public Map(ushort w, ushort h) {
        width = w;
        height = h;
        cells = new Cell[width, height](); //The error is located right here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the parentheses when initializing the array.

Answer (score 3):

Initialize the multi-dimensional array without using parenthesis:

```
cells = new Cell[width, height];
```

Comment: Waow, god damn, thanks :) Been using System.Collections and System.Collections.Generic too much I guess. Haha :)

Comment: No worries, theses things happen :)

Answer (score 0):

Error is in the last line as pointed below; remove the `()`

```
cells = new Cell[width, height]();
                                <--Here
```

Comment: Also thanks to you :) My issue is it give me line number and column number, but I have no way to see column in my IDE (MonoDevelop 4).
So a side question would be, do you know how to display that in MonoDevelop? :)

Comment: @Jomik, Nope, have never used it.